# Inserting documents to MongoDB using node.js and mongoshell

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, backend

I havee this Json format:

```
{
    "AAPL": {
        "cname": "Apple inc",
        "symbol": "AAPL",
        "logo": "apple.png",
        "price": 0
    },
    "NVDA": {
        "cname": "Nvidia Corporation",
        "symbol": "NVDA",
        "logo": "nvidia.png",
        "price": 0
     },
    "GOOG": {
        "cname": "Google inc",
        "symbol": "GOOG",
        "logo": "google.png",
        "price": 0
    }
}
```

I'd like to keep the same format while inserting to the mongoDB.
How can i do that using mongoDB native driver for node.js and using the mongo shell.

Comment: Do you want each stock in a separate document (likely good idea) or one document with all stocks (likely bad idea)?

Comment: Each stock in a separate doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a single JSON object here. When you want each of its keys to be a separate document, you need to transform the object into an array first. While you do that, you also need to move the stock-symbol which is the key of each sub-object into the object itself so it doesn't get lost in the process. You can do this with a Javascript for-in loop:

```
jsonObject = ... // that JSON code you posted above

var docs = [];
for (var key in jsonObject) {
     var doc = jsonObject[key];
     doc.symbol = key;
     docs.push(doc);
}
```

You can then pass the whole array to [`db.collection.insert`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/) to make a batch-insert of all documents in that array.